# TransactionScope - excluding connection

Tags: vb.net

Please see the below:

```
Using scope As New System.Transactions.TransactionScope
//Create instance of connection 1 and open 
//Create instance of connection 2 and open
//Create instance of connection 3 and open
scope.complete()
End Using
```

Is there a way of excluding connection 2 from the transaction.  The reason is because the database server that connection2 connects to does not have Transactions enabled.  I am planning to enable it but it has to go through the "change process", which takes weeks.  Therefore I am looking for a quick win.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create the 2nd connection before the transaction:

```
//Create instance of connection 2 and open
Using scope As New System.Transactions.TransactionScope
//Create instance of connection 1 and open 
//Create instance of connection 3 and open
scope.complete()
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks+1.  The probles is that coneection1 is in funtion1, connection2 in function2 and connection3 in function3.  I would have to pass connection objects around.  Is there another way?